# .docx, .csv Files not getting copied from Intermediate Container to Target Container Image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, ubuntu-16.04, gitlab-ci

I can see my .docx / .pdf / .csv files in the intermediate container,
But they are not getting copied to the target container image at the end.

Anything i am missing here ?

**Edited**:

Here is my DockerFile:

```
# docker build -t name:<$VERSION>-<$RELEASE> .

FROM builder-dotnet-nodejs:latest AS build-env
ENV NODE_OPTIONS="--max_old_space_size=4096"

WORKDIR /app

# Copy everything and build
COPY / ./

RUN dotnet dev-certs https -ep ./cert/dev-cert.pfx -p dev && \
    dotnet publish -c release -o out -r linux-x64

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-stretch-slim
ENV HTTPPORT=80 \
    HTTPSPORT=443

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
COPY / ./ #This line has helped me with copying all files over again, Not sure if this is the best solution !
CMD exec ./app_name -HttpPort:$HTTPPORT -HttpsPort:$HTTPSPORT -sqltype:ms
```

Comment: can you show the Dockerfile?

Comment: @Adiii,
I have added the DockerFile,
these all operations are handled by Gitlab-CI

Answer (score 1):

You are copying only a single file (`/app/out`) from the `build-env` into the final container

```
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
```

You will need to copy all the files if you want them there (don'f forget the slash `./`).

```
COPY --from=build-env /app/* ./
```

minimal example

```
FROM builder-dotnet-nodejs:latest AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ ./

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-stretch-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/* ./
```